# How can I write the following lambda expression in one line?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, expression

I want to fetch the records as follows

**SearchResult.condition** is null then fetch all the rows from **Person**

if **SearchResult.condition** is false then fetch  the rows where **PersonType** column contains null value

if **SearchResult.condition** is true then fetch  the rows where **PersonType** column contains non null value

```
 struct SearchResult
 {
     public string Name;
     public bool? condition; 
 }

 Expression<Func<Person, bool>> expression;
 if(condition==null)
 {
     expression= (a =>
        (SearchResult.Name==null || a.Name == SearchResult.Name)
     );
 } 

else if(condition.Value == true)
 {
    expression= (a =>
    (SearchResult.Name==null || a.Name == SearchResult.Name)
    && a.PersonType != null)
 } 
 else if(condition.Value == false)
 {
    expression= (a =>
    (SearchResult.Name==null || a.Name == SearchResult.Name)
    && a.PersonType == null)
 }
```

I want to write the expression in one expression instead of using if else conditions. Can u plz help me in it?

Comment: Do you want the value of `condition.Value` to count at the evaluation of the expression or when the expression is created? I also guess this is part of a bigger problem, what is that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could shorten as:

```
expression = a => 
    (SearchResult.Name == null || a.Name == SearchResult.Name) && 
    (SearchResult.condition == null || Search.condition == (a.PersonType != null));
```

Answer (score 5):

Well you *can* do it with a conditional operator, but you need to specify the type of the expression tree for each lambda expression:

```
var expression = condition == null
    ? (Expression<Func<Person, bool>>) a => SearchResult.Name == null || 
                                            a.Name == SearchResult.Name
    : condition.Value
    ? (Expression<Func<Person, bool>>) a => (SearchResult.Name == null || 
                                             a.Name == SearchResult.Name) &&
                                            a.PersonType != null
    : (Expression<Func<Person, bool>>) a => (SearchResult.Name == null || 
                                             a.Name == SearchResult.Name) &&
                                            a.PersonType == null;
```

But assuming you're going to use this with a LINQ query, you'd be much better off with something like:

```
var query = foo.Where(a => SearchResult.Name == null ||
                           a.Name == SearchResult.Name);
if (condition != null)
{
    query = condition.Value ? query.Where(a => a.PersonType != null)
                            : query.Where(a => a.PersonType == null);
}
```

As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to avoid writing mutable structs or using public fields.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jon. but the condition is everything. I have to call a generic method to find out the count of resulting records first and then will have to call the reusable method to get the all records matching this condition.